# How does one include a node module dependency in a Vitest test for a React component?

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, vite, react-testing-library, vitest

The component is very simple:

```
return (
  <Label htmlFor={id}>
    <Input
      type={'text'}
      id={id}
      ref={ref}
    />
  </Label>
);
```

`ref` is created here:

```
const { ref } = useResizeObserver<HTMLInputElement>();
```

And `useResizeObserver` is from a node module:

```
import useResizeObserver from 'use-resize-observer';
```

My Vitest test is very simple too:

```
it('', async () => {
  render(<MyTextInput />);
  ...
};
```

When I run my Vitest test I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: ResizeObserver is not defined
```

My `vite.config.ts` file looks like this:

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import VitePluginLinaria from 'vite-plugin-linaria';
import { configDefaults, defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), VitePluginLinaria()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    css: true,
    setupFiles: './src/__tests__/setup.ts',
  },
});
```

My `setup.ts` file looks like this:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import { afterEach } from 'vitest';

import { cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';

afterEach(() => {
  cleanup();
});
```

I have tried adding the following to the `test` object in `vite.config.ts`:

```
include: [...configDefaults.include, '**/node_modules/use-resize-observer'],
```

I have tried adding the following to both my `setup.ts` file and my test file itself:

```
import 'use-resize-observer';
```

Neither of them have worked.

Does anyone have any other ideas, please?

Comment: The dependency _is_ being included, but the global it's expecting doesn't exist in JSDOM - https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/3368.

Comment: Thank you Jon, your comment put me on the right track

Comment: ResizeObserver can  be mocked via Vitest's vi function as described here: https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#globals